# Extracting Value from column

Tags: r

I have this dataset, I paste only few data

```
"73C23" "62R31" "62M26" "58C44" "53R02" NA      "78R58" "76C63"
```

I'm trying to write a function that does the following operations on strings:
The first two numerical values must be extracted and compared with the parameter 18. If > 18 must be added to 1900, if <= must be added to 2000 and make a separate Year column.
The central letter must be compared with this legend: mesi_legend

```
head(mesi_legend)
  January February March April May June
      "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "H"
```

And it is written on another column

While for the last final numbers must be extracted normally if male, subtracted 40 if female (as a discrimine I can use > 31, subtract 40 but I have margin of error I think.

I start from this:

```
"GFNNTN78R58G812M"

first step> "78R58"


Output_of_my_function(78R58) > Year 1978
                               Month October
                               Day 18
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: your question is confusing kindly provide us the detailed statement as well as reproducible example using dput(your df )

Comment: also 78R58 in where is the value of R in mesi_legend

Answer (score 0):

Here something you can start with and it's easy to scale. Using `gsub` and grouping we can split your string into 3 parts separated by _, which will help us later when we use `tidyr::separate` to get Y, M, and D

```
> gsub('(\\d{2})([A-Z])(\\d{2})','\\1_\\2_\\3',"73C23") 
[1] "73_C_23"

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% mutate(X1= gsub('(\\d{2})([A-Z])(\\d{2})','\\1_\\2_\\3',X)) %>% 
    separate(X1,sep = '_',into = c('Year','Month','Day')) %>% 
    mutate(
    Month=case_when(Month=='A' ~ 'Jan',
                    Month=='B' ~ 'Feb',
                    Month=='R' ~ 'Oct',
                    TRUE ~ NA_character_),
    Year=if_else(Year>18, paste0(19,Year),paste0(20,Year)),
    Day=if_else(gsub('.*([A-Z])$','\\1',Y)=='M',as.numeric(Day)-40,as.numeric(Day)-30)
  )
```

## Data

```
df <- data.frame(X=c("78R58","62R31","62M26",NA),
              Y=c("GFNNTN78R58G812M","GFNNTN78R58G812F","GFNNTN78R58G812M",NA))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! i take this approach, but in my mind i have this block:i create 3 object with substr(), ext_anno wher extract first tow, ext_mese where extrat third, ext_giorno where extract last two.